# Suppose $S$ is a minimal surface, show that the gaussian curvative is negative on all interior points

Tags: curvature, minimal-surfaces

I am trying to improve my proving skills, started learning by myself, can anybody help me with this?

thanks you

Comment: I'd just like to say, your question doesn't make it clear that it's related to minimum surfaces.

Comment: I tried to re-tag this but ran into a snag with some "wiki edit priviledge" gizmo.  But probably someone should!

Comment: Please don't change your question to something else. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: Also, what sort of course are you following that you can talk about minimal surfaces but don't know the derivative of $x^2+x$?

Comment: Why do you keep re-writing your questions? *please stop*!

Answer (score 4):

One definition of a minimal surface is that its mean curvature is zero at each of its points. If $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are the principal curvatures then $\tfrac{1}{2}(\kappa_1+\kappa_2)=0$.

Recall that the Gaussian curvature is given by the product $\kappa_1\kappa_2$.

If $\tfrac{1}{2}(\kappa_1+\kappa_2)=0$ then $\kappa_2 = -\kappa_1$ and so the Gaussian curvature is $\kappa_1\kappa_2 = -\kappa_1^2 \le 0$.

The case $\kappa_1=\kappa_2=0$ gives a plane and both the mean and the Gaussian curvatures are zero.

Comment: can you show me proof that mean curative is zero  ?

Comment: Minimal surfaces are *defined* to be surfaces with zero mean curvature: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalSurface.html

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface#Definitions

Comment: To Fly by Night:  Did you perchance mean to type " . . . both the mean and the Gaussian curvatures are *zero*" in your final sentence?

Comment: @RobertLewis Absolutely! Thanks for that.

Comment: @Fly by Night:  Glad to help out; BUT, how the hell did this answer end up with *this* question?  Any ideas?

Comment: The OP changed the title to a different question.

Comment: @Casteels:  *way* different!  Is the other question still around somewhere?

Comment: @RobertLewis The OP *totally* rewrote the question. What's the policy on that? The software won't let you delete a question with answers, so surely people shouldn't be able to nuke a question.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer added at the advice of Javier Badia; see comments below:  this answer was posted to a version of the question which was such a radical revision of the current (rolled back) question that it is really about a completely different topic.  The question I answered was, basically:  what is the derivative of $x^2 + x$?  Apparently the OP put it through some rather severe revisions.  So forgive me if this answer seems, well, rather curious for the current version of the question.  Thanks for your patience.  Robert Lewis***

Oh well, while we're at it, might as well answer the *new* question, since I'm on this page and it's not *too* hard:

If

$y(x) = x^2 + x, \tag{1}$

then

$y'(x) = 2x + 1; \tag{2}$

and just for the sake of completeness:

given (1), we have

$y(x + h) = (x + h)^2 + (x + h); \tag{3}$

$y(x + h) = x^2 + 2xh + h^2 + x + h; \tag{4}$

$y(x + h) - y(x) = x^2 + 2xh + h^2 + x + h - x^2 - x; \tag{5}$

$y(x + h) - y(x) = 2xh + h^2 + h; \tag{6}$

$(y(x + h) - y(x)) / h = 2x + h + 1 = 2x + 1 + h; \tag{7}$

$y'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}(y(x + h) - y(x)) / h = \lim_{h \to 0}(2x + h + 1) = 2x + 1; \tag{8}$

QED!!!

Hope this helps answer the *new* question!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I rolled the question back to what it was originally. You should probably add a disclaimer to your answer so people don't start downvoting you.

Comment: @Javier Badia:  Thanks, will do.

Comment: @Javier Badia:  how did you "roll back" the question?

Comment: I just clicked "edit" and then "roll back" on the first revision, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Javier Badia:  yeah, thanks, will give it a try!

Comment: The question has been re-written for the third time.